# Save when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android, button, save

In my android app, when the back button is pressed I want the app to save. This is my code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.d("VIVZ", counter + "Was Saved");
}
```

So when i press the back button  It exits the app and then when I go back into the app It has not saved.

Comment: You have no code that saves anything

Comment: add more to identify problem

Comment: what you want to save on back button pressed where you defined your counter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 'back' press the Activity is expected to be finished - its instance state is lost. You won't e.g. get `onSaveInstanceState()` invoked - which is a method helping in preserving activity instance state.

If you want to save app state (if your counter belongs there) it is probably the easiest to use `SharedPreferences`. Even in that case probably you could consider placing state-saving code in `onStop()` rather than in `onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Do your saving code
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the activity lifecycle methods instead.

```
@Override
onPause(){

    //use some kind of SharedPreferences class or FileOutputStream
    //because onPause() is called when the activity is removed from the ui

}
```